# Spread BibLaTeX sets across multiple lines

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, citing

Using BibLaTEX's `subentry` as in `\usepackage[backend=biber,subentry]{biblatex}` to bundle multiple references into one citation via `\defbibentryset{set1}{ref1,...,refn}`, how can I have each reference start on a new line within the corresponding entry in the list of references?

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for `block=par`, which adds line breaks even within individual references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we examine the punctuation that is being added we see:

[image: Added punctuation]

So something like

```
\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\addperiod\par}
```

should do the job, probably.